# ListFieldIterator shows ["Title" column value]

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I am writing a webpart for SP 2007 with ListFieldIterator.
If ControlMode equal to SPControlMode.Edit or SPControlMode.New it works good. If ControlMode equal SPControlMode.Dispaly i see ["Title" column value] for Title column and ["SomeColumn" column value] for each other columns.

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This typically happens when the ListFieldIterator control does not have the itemContext set or the controlmode is unset/not parseable. Have you tried explicitly setting these two attributes?
PS. in your question you have "Dispaly", not "Display" - I believe it's a typo

Comment: You missed the typo on the typo  :)